# How do I start a new instance of PHP in Windows without it opening a new CMD window?

Tags: php, windows, background, exec, xampp

I want multiple PHP processes to run in the background without disturbing the user. This is the code I have:

```
exec("psexec -d php peak.php map/eline/updatedotrange first=$first last=$last filename=$filename > NUL 2> NUL");
```

But for every exec statement, a new CMD pops up. This kinda ruins it for me when I'm looping 100 times and running that line.

Any way I can get the process to run in the background, without the user noticing?

Comment: Does `start /B php x.php` work?  I think I may have used something like that about 10 years ago.  See: http://zeroflag.wordpress.com/2007/05/12/start-command/

Comment: I have tried that. There is actually no difference in the results of  `start /B php` and `php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using `bgrun.exe`

http://www.jukkis.net/bgrun/

If anyone knows a 100% native Windows way to do this I'd die to know