# Close PHP CLI window on script completion

Tags: php, powershell, command-line

I have a basic PHP script I am running through Windows Task Scheduler. The task runs well, but doesn't close the window once the script has completed. The script runs every minute, and we quickly get our server overran by the completed php.exe windows. Is there a way to close the CLI window if the script has completed?

I've searched around, but haven't found a clean answer. I'd prefer not to schedule another task to terminate php.exe if at all possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with setting up tasks in the scheduler, but can you add `exit;` at the end of the script details?

Comment: That is a good idea, let me check. I have exit; set if it fails, but i dont think it has failed yet.

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048299/how-do-i-start-a-new-instance-of-php-in-windows-without-it-opening-a-new-cmd-win

Comment: exit does not work. it does terminate the script, but not the window

Comment: add this at the end of your call > NUL 2 > &1